# Visual studio 2010 solution explorer settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

I got a fairly large (C++) project in Visual studio 2010. Somehow I managed to click "Show all files" in the solution explorer and now a bug in visual studio 2010 is preventing me from uncheck the option.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614417/visual-studio-crashes-when-switching-solution-explorers-view

Do anyone here know where the this setting is stored? I've searched the solution file, project files, filter files without finding anything.

Comment: I see that bug has been closed as fixed. I wonder if that's something included in the SP1 beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C#, similar user-specific data is stored in SolutionName.suo (hidden) and ProjectName.csproj.user files. See if you have what might be the equivalent files for C++. You can freely delete these files to reset user-specific settings, which should restore solution explorer to its default view.

Comment: that did the trick, removed the .user file and the .suo file and the setting reset.

Comment: Exit Visual Studio before deleting the hidden <solutionname>.suo file. I tried only closing the solution, that did not work. I think exisint VS, deleting the files and starting VS is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to those programming in C++, for VS 2010 C++ these files are:

> ProjectName.suo
>   ProjectName.vcxproj.user